# Using where clause when Select clause contain Case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Im working on Oracle SQL and I tried to filter some of my result by using where clause. In addition, on the same query I have case in select clause. for some reason I`m getting error during running the query and I dont understand what is the problem. Query attached:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN TBL_120.PP_ID!=TBL_200.PP_ID  THEN TBL_120.pp_id
 END 
  FROM
 (select pp_id, code, amount from price_plan_mapping where  pcversion_id = 
 '10200') TBL_120 LEFT JOIN 
 (select pp_id, code, amount from price_plan_mapping where  pcversion_id = 
 '20000') TBL_200 ON  TBL_120.PP_ID=TBL_200.PP_ID
 WHERE TBL_120.PP_ID!=TBL_200.PP_ID IS NOT NULL
```

I want to filler out all the results which are coming from the case codition with null.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What error are you getting?  Your problem is in the non-sensical `where` clause.  I would suggest that you ask another question, with sample data, desired results, and a explanation of your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE TBL_120.PP_ID != TBL_200.PP_ID IS NOT NULL
```

probably should be

```
WHERE TBL_120.PP_ID != TBL_200.PP_ID
  AND TBL_200.PP_ID IS NOT NULL
```